# Maven multi module project failed snapshot dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have a project with many modules that produce jars.
a module is an assembly that puts all those jars and some others in a zip.

when i do mvn install on the parent project everything works normally.
if i do mvn deploy or mvn -U deploy all modules compile and are uploaded
except assembly. which stops with an error on a SNAPSHOT dependency not found.
This dependency is always one of the modules that has just been uploaded.
in the error message it says a number like
config:jar:2.0.0-20180726.155101-11 and this number is still the previous uploaded, not the last one just done.

As if assembly was looking on nexus the previous version of SNAPSHOT to the one just generated.

in a random it always falls on one of the modules of the project.

Thank JYT